# How to Restrict '$' symbol for some rows only in RDLC?

Tags: .net, rdlc

I have a report with column names "Department Name",  "Total". If Department Name = "Gas" then  the value should display in total like '1234', else in all other cases it should display along with '$' like '$1234'. How can i achieve this in RDLC. Is it possible for some rows only?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression like this in the `Format` property of the Total textbox:

```
=IIf(Fields!DepartmentName.Value = "Gas", "f2", "c2")
```